# Date Format for 07/15/2012 09:31:45 PM

Tags: jquery, telerik

I need a date format for above date ,my code is like this

```
function formatDateTime(date) { return $.telerik.formatString('{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss}', date); }
```

but it shows 07/15/2012 09:31:45 only , misses the AM and PM,but i need with AM and PM,can anyone help?

Thanks,

Comment: refer this link http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-date-format-pattern.html  for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
function formatDateTime(date) { return $.telerik.formatString('{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}', date);
```